# Archiving RDS to S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to archive RDS based on a time limit and a status condition of a record. The database has many tables, and all related tables should also be archived.

I have access to S3 so can send the archives there.

Almost all of the solutions I have found so far require partitioning, however partitioning isn't particularly helpful to me as I have related tables that also need to be archived (unless I've missed something about partitioning).

I was planning on creating archive tables in a different schema, and then have pg_cron job copy data over and then purge from the main tables. But I'm not sure how best to get these archive tables then transported to s3.

Has anyone had any experience doing this please? and any advice?

Many thanks

Comment: It appears that you want to 'move' data from Amazon RDS Postgres to Amazon S3 and then delete the data from Postgres. Your first consideration should be **how you will use the data in future** -- for example, do you want the ability to reload the data to Postgres in future, or perhaps you want the ability to query the data in the S3 bucket by using Amazon Athena? Please let us know how you _intend_ to use the exported data and then we could recommend an appropriate format and method for the export.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. The archived files will be used for interrogation by powerbi. They are not intended for restoration, as we have backups running on RDS already.

Comment: What format does PowerBI require when accessing data from an Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: CSV is fine as far as I know

Comment: In that case, you could simply [Export data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html). It saves it in CSV format, but beware of multi-line fields and fields using quotes and commas.